# What can replace the pleasure of food?

Tags: weight-loss, health

I often feel tired with my work, I don't like it, but I have to do it. I also feel my life is full of unhappiness, I can't find any joy expect from food.

So when I am sad I eat more. I know this is not good, but this is the only way I feel happy, so I become fatter, I also tried to eat less but this make me feel more lone and sad.

I think I should become happier, but I don't know what to do.

I also want to lose weight, what I should do ?

Comment: The first thing could be if you can find a person you like and trust and discuss this with him/her. In the perspective, you need to find the work you will be in peace with, not that you just work because you have to.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think this is a valid question.  I recently started Time Restricted Eating (TRE).  I eat my first carbohydrate of the day at noon, and my last carbohydrate of the day around six pm.  This creates about five waking hours in the morning when I'm not eating and about four hours in the evening when I'm not eating.  The morning fasting isn't hard, but not eating in the evening creates a feeling that is a lot like loneliness!  We live in a society with an epidemic of loneliness, and many people, including myself, tend to use food as a substitute for healthy relationships with other humans.

Anyway, I just wanted to say that what you are feeling is valid.  As far as a solution, that is harder, and gets into Psychology.  There are people on this board who will jump on my ass if I started talking about psychology, because that isn't the subject of this board. I'll just say, take walks, join a book club, get away from your computer, meditate, get blue light bulbs for the morning and blue filtered light bulbs for the evening.  If at all possible, get away from chat boards like this one and find real friends.  Read the book "lost connections".

Comment: Thank you very much, you let me know that i'm not alone,i wil find myself something meaningful to do, so that i will forget thinking about food. thanks for the twice.